# fields created by class are not being caught by jquery listener and event not firing

Tags: jquery, forms, listener

I have a form that is created by looping through an array:

```
  $fields = array('firstName' => array(   'id' => 'firstName',
                                    'name'=>'firstName',
                                    'label'=>'First Name',
                                    'class'=>'fill',
                                    'size'=>'32',
                                    'maxLength'=>'32'),

            'lastName' => array(    'id' => 'lastName',
                                    'name'=>'lastName',
                                    'label'=>'Last Name',
                                    'class'=>'fill',
                                    'size'=>'32',
                                    'maxLength'=>'32'),
```

the results of this are passed to a class that builds the form:

```
 $form = new Form;
 echo "<div class='leftCenter'>" . $form->text($id,$name,$class,"someValue",$size,$maxLength) . "</div>";
```

the class:

```
class Form{
    public function text($id,$name,$class,$value,$maxLength,$size)
    {
            $str = "<input type='text' name='" . $id . "' id='" . $name. "' value='" . $value . "' size='" . $size . "' maxLength='" . $maxSize . "'>\n";
            return $str;
    }
 }
```

and the results:

```
    <input type='text' name='firstName' id='firstName' class='fill' size='12' maxLength='32'>
    <input type='text' name='lastName' id='lastName' class='fill' size='12' maxLength='32'>
```

I have a jquery listener that is listening for a change event

```
    $('.fill').on('change', function(){
            alert($(this).val());
    });
```

i have also tried

```
    $('.fill').blur(function(){
            alert($(this).val());
    });
```

and

```
    $('.fill').change(function(){
            alert($(this).val());
    });
```

interestingly enough, if i copy/paste the input line results from the class and the jquery into fiddle it works fine.  Im guessing theres a delegation issue of some kind...

everything works great except I cant get the alert to fire....

Comment: Did you include jQuery and remember the document.ready function

Comment: I did remember both this time :)(

Comment: Do you create your form before bind it?

Comment: And it's not really dynamic, as in inserted with javascript, it's created and outputted with PHP right ?

Comment: thats correct adeneo.  edited title to be correct.

Comment: what do you mean fasouto?

Comment: Any errors in the console? Try logging `$('.fill').length` etc ?

Comment: added         var len = $('.fill').length;        console.log(len);  and got 0

Comment: Try to eliminate possible reasons. get read of the php and try to output the form directly, as html. when done, if the problem still occurs, update your question accordingly. I am sure that it's pure jquery issue, so the rest of the code is irrelevant. AND, of-course, fiddle it please

Comment: you are correct Yossi, if i created form directly with passing to class, it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, this is a delegation issue.  Since those elements do not exist in the DOM at the time of render.  The event will not get attached properly.  You need to attach the event to an element that already exists (such as the body element), and then use a delegate the handler to your inputs with class of fill.  Try this:

```
$( "body" ).on( "change", ".fill", function() {
    alert( 'test');
 });
```

I hope this helps!  You will want to put that code in a document ready handler.